# App page sorting after app uninstall

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, uninstallation

My Galaxy S3-alpha runs Android version 4.1.1. Recently I uninstalled some of the apps I didn't use. But when I go into the "Apps" page, with all the apps lined up, the places of the old apps (that were un-installed) is still empty! So there is a lot of empty space between the apps that make navigation between them hard. I have also tried restarting the phone several times, the OS has also been updated once, but the empty space in the apps page remains! I wanted to see if there is a way that once an app is un-installed its place won't be left empty in the apps window.

Or more generally, is there a way I can sort the apps in the apps page so for example they can be sorted by their name or date installed?

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you are using a stock launcher (maybe Samsung's TouchWiz) that leaves empty spaces when you uninstall an app.

If you are using Samsung Galaxy S4 (using stock launcher), you can go to the Apps screen, and `click on left menu key > View type > Alphabetical grid`. If you are not on an S4, see if you can find something similar to this.

If you do not have the `Alphabetical grid` option, you can install a 3rd party launcher like [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher). Nova can sort your app drawer alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is Samsung then try this: tap over the menu icon (down left) then tap `Edit`. Now you are in **edit mode**, you can tell because there are markers at each corner of each app icon. In this mode you can drag and drop the icons, they do not need to be in alphabetical order.

Note: I think Edit is only present if you are in **custom mode**. You can switch to custom mode at any time going to `Left menu > View Type > Custom`.